# JQPlot How to toggle line smoothing on and off

Tags: jqplot

Would like to toggle some of the JQPlot options on/off with checkboxes for a plot that is already rendered in the browser.

The options are defined in a separate variable similar to below:

```
var options = {
    title: "Options Example",
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {
        unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
    },
    series: [{
        rendererOptions : {smooth: true},
        showMarker: isShowMarker 
    }]  
};
```

Plot works great and am having no trouble toggling on/off line markers or even lines drawn with canvasOverlay. But cannot toggle line smoothing on and off.

Have tried several options:

```
options.series.renderOptions.smooth = false;
plot1.series.smooth = false;
plot1.series[0].smooth = false;
plot1.series[0].data[0].smooth = false;
```

... with all of the above options followed by plot1.replot();.

Any suggestions on the command to change smoothing on/off with checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading many, many examples I finally found the basic solution that works with all option changes. The solution comes from [this extended example](https://github.com/vpassapera/jqPlot/blob/master/examples/kcp_pyramid_by_age.php).

You simply create a new options variable, include the changes to the options, and then replot the graph with the options variable as an argument in the replot as below.

For my smoothing problem:

```
var options2 = { seriesDefaults: { rendererOptions: { smooth: this.checked } } };       
plot1.replot(options2);
```

Hope this helps others needing dynamic option changes of any kind.

Comment: This option can solve it too : **plot1.series[0].rendererOptions.smooth = false;** Firebug can be very useful in this kind of search : just using **console.log(plot1);** you can easily travel into your plot element.

Comment: AnthonyLeGovic, tried that option as well but it does not seem to work. Could be my overall options definition conflicting with it. Thank you for the lead on console.log() in Firebug.

Comment: This helps me needing dynamic option changes of any kind. :-)